# Custom Input Format In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, format

I have a view named `CreateProject.cshtml` that it strongly type of `CreateProjectViewModel` when i want do use custom format for One of inputs that for this use Following Code in `CreateProjectViewModel` :

```
   [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###,###.####}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
   public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Well I try this way but worked also use Following Code :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ProjectPrice, new { @Value = Model.ProjectPrice.ToString("0:###,###.####") })
```

Still does not work, For solve this problem i see other questions.

Also I should add that I Use Automapper for mapping ViewModels and tried create custom format with [formatter.js](http://firstopinion.github.io/formatter.js/index.html) but still does not work.

at the end

I Have following format

```
22,222,222 // this is currency
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For formatting textbox value you can use jquery masked input plugin: http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

At first you should include jquery plugin: https://jquery.com/

Than you can use following code:

```
$("#ProjectPrice").mask("99,999,999")
```

Comment: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Link-only answers are difficult to understand and are susceptible to become invalid if the website is down or not working. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can reproduce the most relevant portions of the link/blog you are referring to into this post itself.